# Well-definedness of a set whose members are sequences

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ are normed linear spaces and $T:X\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator. Let $B_X:=\{x\in X:~\|x\|\leq 1\}.$ Define

$$\mathbb{A}:=\{(x_n)\subseteq B_X:~\|Tx_n\|\to \|T\|\}.$$

Note that $\mathbb{A}$ is a collection of sequences (which may be constant). Also, if $(x_n)$ is a member of $\mathbb{A}$, its all possible subsequences are also member of $\mathbb{A}$.

Is this collection well-defined?? I have never worked with this types of sets. I apologize, if my question is trivial. Is there any other way to describe these types of sets.

Comment: Sure, it's well-defined, although the notation could be a bit clearer perhaps.

Comment: Can you kindly help me with the notation@JairTaylor

Comment: It really just depends on the context and your audience.  $(x_n) \subseteq B_x$ is not strictly true because $(x_n)$ is a sequence, not a set, and it also may be unclear that $(x_n)$ is a whole sequence and not a number (although this is pretty standard.). However if this notation is understood then it is not an issue.

Comment: Thankyou@JairTaylor for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would it not be? From $B_X$ you can construct the set of all sequences in $B_X$ as the set of all functions from $\Bbb{N}$ to $B_X$. Then you take the subset specified by the condition
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}||T(x_n)||=||T||.$$